# Starting with Zurb foundation without Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zurb-foundation

I want to use Zurb but I don't want to program websites in ruby. Can I use Zurb with PHP?

I got confused when Zurb manuals instruct you to install several RubyGems.
Installing those packages will not be a problem, but can I develop websites in PHP on top of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at this page: http://foundation.zurb.com/download.php

In fact, Foundation can be downloaded/installed in several different ways.

One of them is to install some Gems in a Ruby (RoR) project, but this isn't the only way. You can download it as pure CSS and JS (for the wanted JS plugins) and integrate it in your PHP project, or by using Sass + compass or bourbon or... (look at 'Using Sass Standalone' on this page: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html )

Comment: Well, more or less yes. But you do can use Sass + compass in a PHP project, here is an article on how to do so: http://andrewkandels.com/sass-and-compass-for-non-ruby-developers . I'm sure you can find others by googling: "compass sass php". Of course, I think the easiest way to integrate Foundation in a PHP project is to go along with pure CSS/JS integration. You just have to download the files from the download page I gave you and put them in the right place in your PHP project. :)

Answer (score 1):

Rails doesn't have anything to do with Zurb. If you want to work with php, for example using Sf2 which is one of the best PHP framework out there, you can use this bundle which will help you including Zurb Foundation to your project : https://github.com/bmatzner/BmatznerFoundationBundle

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has nothing to do with it. Just download the default css from here http://foundation.zurb.com/download.php. Actually you don't even need PHP, you can include it in basic HTML page just as usual CSS styles :)